# Byte data to download a word file asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stream, arrays

I have a dataset with two tables. The first tells me that its a doc file. The second contains the byte array for the file. However I need to take out the first 85 bytes as they contain the OLE Object header created by Access. I have this so far. .

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int examId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["exam_id"]);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RHD_CS"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_spirometry_readexam";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@iExamID", SqlDbType.Int);

        cmd.Parameters["@iExamID"].Value = examId;

        string sFileName = "exam" + examId.ToString()+".";

        DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter daData = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        daData.Fill(dsData);

        DataRow drDocData = dsData.Tables[1].Rows[0];
        byte[] bDocData =  (byte[])drDocData["exam_binary"];


        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= filename.doc");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bDocData);
        Response.End();
```

This works but when the document is downloaded it's just a bunch of gibberish.

Solved
Thanks for all of the help. I solved the problem by using a stream then converting it back to a byte.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int examId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["exam_id"]);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RHD_CS"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_spirometry_readexam";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@iExamID", SqlDbType.Int);

        cmd.Parameters["@iExamID"].Value = examId;

        string sFileName = "exam" + examId.ToString()+".";

        DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter daData = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        daData.Fill(dsData);


        DataRow drDocData = dsData.Tables[1].Rows[0];
        byte[] bDocData =  (byte[])drDocData["exam_binary"];
        Label1.Text = bDocData.Length.ToString();

       Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bDocData);
       stream.Position = 85;

       bDocData = ReadFully(stream);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= insert filename.doc");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bDocData);
        Response.End();
   }

  public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: `<byte[]>.Skip(85)` for the data. And `<byte[]>.Take(85)` for the header? Note that `<byte[]>` is a placeholder.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ where would this go in my code? would I do this to my bDocData array?

Comment: yes to the byte[] from which you need to extract the header and the data

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
//Create a dummy GridView
GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataSource = dsData.Tables[1];//Assign datatable to gridview source
GridView1.DataBind();

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
    "attachment;filename=DataTable.doc");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```